# Upload failure from google api client

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

Google API gave this error:

> Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.

This occurred at this line:

```
request.Upload();
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the quickstart guide from the Google Drive SDK docs to learn how to upload a file to Google Drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart

Comment: Please drill down through the exception to find out the detailed error message. As an alternative, you can install Fiddler and capture the HTTP request and response.

Comment: thanks man , the response from Fiddler realy helped me to understands that issue.

Comment: Would you like to share what the issue was?